# ManytoMany Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have the following field:

```
/**
 * Many Organization have Many PartnerCategory.
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PartnerCategory", inversedBy="organizations")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="partnercategory_organization_map",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="partnercategory_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $partnerCategories;
```

how can i make Unique to false!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just disable uniqueness since result table of `ManyToMany` association have both columns as primary key.

Create your own association class `PartnerCategoryOrganization` which will contain links between categories and organizations with `ManyToOne` relation to the both entities. Then replace `ManyToMany` with `OneToMany` relation on `PartnerCategory` and `Organization` entities.